# Submit Only One of Two toggling forms

Tags: php, javascript, html, submit, undefined

I have two different forms which are being included in a php file. Their visibility is based on a onClick JS toggle function. The toggle works great. However if I was to fill only one of the forms out and click its respective submit button, I get sent back to the same page rather than the action.php file that i have specifed with this in the broswer:

```
http://localhost/?user_temp=f&pass_temp1=f&pass_temp2=ff&email_temp=f&answer1=3&submitbtn=Signup+Now
```

And this Javascript error: "TypeError undefined document.hform.sSecureUser

Both Forms also have their own javascripts to MD5 some data and sSecureUser comes from the Signup Form.

Interestingly, if I was to remove one of the inlcude forms leaving only the Submit form lets say, it would work. It seems that these forms' javascript is clashing with one another :/ ...

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459012/multiple-forms-and-one-processing-page) but it didnt work for me since each one of my forms is using java script. PLEASE HELP AND THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!... Let me know if you would like to see any of my forms, javascript, or php files...

Toggle Code:

```
<div>
<a href="/forms/login-form.php" onclick="toggle_visibility('login-div'); return false;">Login</a>
    <div id="login-div" style="display:none">
        <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/forms/login-form.php');?>         
    </div>
<a href="/forms/signup-form.php" onclick="toggle_visibility('signup-div'); return false;">Sign up</a>
    <div id="signup-div" style="display:none">
        <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/forms/signup-form.php'); ?>           
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                function toggle_visibility(id) {
                        var e = document.getElementById(id);
                       if(e.style.display == 'block'){
                          e.style.display = 'none';
                          }
                       else{
                          e.style.display = 'block';
                          }
                }
            //-->
        </script>       
</div>
```

Login Form:

```
<div id="hasJavaScript1" style="display:none">
    <form name="login">
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="user_temp" size=32 maxlength=32><br>
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="pass_temp" size=32 maxlength=32><br>
        <input onClick="passResponse(); return false;" type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Login now">
    </form>

    <form action="/action/login-action.php" METHOD="POST" name="hform">
        <input type="hidden" name="secureuser">
        <input type="hidden" name="securepass">
    </form>
</div>

<script language="javascript" src="/js/md5.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
document.getElementById('hasJavaScript1').style.display = 'block';

function passResponse() {
document.hform.secureuser.value = MD5(document.login.user_temp.value);
document.hform.securepass.value = MD5(document.login.pass_temp.value);
document.login.pass_temp.value = "";
document.hform.submit();

}
// -->
</script>
```

SignUP Form:

```
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/functions/functions.php');?>
<div id="hasJavaScript" style="display:none">
<form name="signup">
    <label>Username</label> <input type="text" name="user_temp" size=32 maxlength=32><span>alphanumeric, no spaces</span><br>
    <label>Type password</label> <input type="password" name="pass_temp1" size=32 maxlength=32><span>alphanumeric, 8-12 long</span><br>
    <label>Retype password</label> <input type="password" name="pass_temp2" size=32 maxlength=32><br>
    <label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email_temp" size=32 maxlength=32><br>
    <label> What is: </label><?php $captchaArray = myCaptcha(); echo $captchaArray['equation'];?><br>
    <label>Answer</label><input type="text" name="answer1">
    <input onClick="passResponse1(); return false;" type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Signup Now">
</form>

<form action="/action/signup-action.php" METHOD="POST" name="signup-hform">
        <input type="hidden" name="sSecureUser">
        <input type="hidden" name="sSecurePass1">
        <input type="hidden" name="sSecurePass2">
        <input type="hidden" name="secureEmail">
        <input type="hidden" name="answer2">
        <input type="hidden" name="checker" value=".<?php echo $captchaArray['answer'];?> .">
</form>
</div>


<script language="javascript" src="/js/md5.js"></script>


  <script language="javascript">
<!--
document.getElementById('hasJavaScript').style.display = 'block';

function passResponse1() {
document.signup-hform.sSecureUser.value = MD5(document.signup.user_temp.value);
document.signup-hform.sSecurePass1.value = MD5(document.signup.pass_temp1.value);
document.signup.pass_temp1.value = "";
document.signup-hform.sSecurePass2.value = MD5(document.signup.pass_temp2.value);
document.signup.pass_temp2.value = "";
document.signup-hform.secureEmail.value = MD5(document.signup.email_temp.value);
document.signup-hform.answer2.value = document.signup.answer1.value;
document.signup.answer1.value = "";
document.signup-hform.submit();

}
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: could you show some code???

Comment: updated thanks for taking an interest @ManishJangir

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with the multiple forms. What's the purpose?

Comment: basically I want to be able to have a page that a user could either log in from or sign up from without being directed to another page. Im doing it for user convenience. With both dropDowns, the user wouldnt have to feel lazy to click to another page.

Comment: Ok, but why the extra forms with hidden fields? Why not just have one form and submit it? You're submitting the hidden forms anyway, that's what I don't get. You may have a valid reason, I just don't see it.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery, or do you want to stick with straight JavaScript? jQuery has `show()` and `hide()` functions that would make your `toggle_visibility` function unnecessary.

Comment: I am using another hidden form so that these inputs are not displayed because they will be handling usernames and passwords. I am using the javascript to MD5 them. As for the jQuery question, I am not familiar with jQuery. But if it would makes things better I wouldnt mind

Comment: Also, `language="javascript"` is deprecated. Use `type="text/javascript"` instead.

Comment: Personally I would do the encryption on the server side after form submit, anyone viewing your page source can now see what encryption you are using.

Comment: OH ok, I thought they would be able to see the post data before it was sent to the server so I added that for more security. http://www.webmastersucks.com/user-login-form-with-javascript-md5/

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you do not specify any value attributes or values in your hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sSecureUser">
<input type="hidden" name="sSecurePass1">
<input type="hidden" name="sSecurePass2">
<input type="hidden" name="secureEmail">
<input type="hidden" name="answer2">
```

But then in your JS, you're trying to access the value attribute.

```
document.hform.sSecureUser.value = ...
```

Try adding values to those. I would also give your hidden forms ids and use the `document.getElementById()` syntax instead of the `document.hform.sSecureUser` syntax.

As far as your form submits, you are suppressing the action of the first form, trying to fill in values for the hidden fields in the second form and then submitting that. Both of your scripts use the same name for the forms `"hform"`. They need to be unique. I would also give them a unique id.

Another possible issue is this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checker" value=".<?php echo $captchaArray['answer'];?> .">
```

You're using the . for string concatenation, but it's not in an echo/print statement. I think it's supposed to be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checker" value="<?php echo $captchaArray['answer'];?>">
```

Comment: i think the way the JS is working is that the document.hform.sSecureUser takes the value from document.signup.user_temp.value (which is defined in the NON HIDDEN FORM). That value is then passed to the hform.... As for the names of the submits. You are right. I changed the second one and will update the code. Now I am only submitting the login form though even while clicking the signUP submit button. but at least i am being take to some action page

Comment: correct me if im wrong about the Javascript^^.. updating the code now to show you waht i did @revent

Comment: Looks better, but your JavaScript functions should have unique names too.

Comment: Ok i think im close. I named the JavaScript function for the Signup form passResponse1 . the login form is working great. just that when i use the submit button the signup form i am getting:
passResponse1 is not defined... changing the code to reflect now

Comment: also :

document.signup-hform.sSecureUser.value = MD5(document.signup.user_temp.value); INVALID ASSIGNMENT LEFT HAND SIDE