# Processing multiple forms in one page using Mongodb and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, mongoose

I am having my sign in and registration form both in the same page. I have specified two different routes for posting the data but it saves sign-in form inputs (which are none) when I hit the register button at the end of the registration form? I looked at this question([Multiple forms and one processing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459012/multiple-forms-and-one-processing-page)). How would it work with node, would that means I have to create a module for different forms?

Here is my code. I have a small script at the end also because the slider function of my bootstrap template was clashing with the submit function.

```
<h2>Register<h2>
<form method="POST" action="/samples"> 
    <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" class="input-lg " placeholder="your full name" data-required="true">
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="input-lg" placeholder="age">
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="input-lg" placeholder="Your City"> 
    <input type="text" name="job" class="input-lg" placeholder="Your Job">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="input-lg " placeholder="prefered username" data-required="true">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="input-lg" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-lg " placeholder="your email" data-required="true">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>

<h2>Login!</h2>
<form method="POST" action="/dashboard">
    <hr class="colorgraph">
    <input type="email" name="emaillog" class="input-lg " placeholder="your email" data-required="true">
    <input type="password" name="passwordlog" class="input-lg" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('button').click( function() {
        $('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, first off because you have two forms, you have to specify which form to submit on a button click.
Right now any button click would submit just the first form.
Give first form's submit button class `registerButton` and second form's submit class `loginButton`.
I would also suggest giving classes to your forms. One will be `registerForm`, another is `loginForm`.
Then change your HTML to reflect the changes

```
<form method="POST" action="/samples" class="registerForm"> 
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary registerButton">Sign in</button>
<form method="POST" action="/dashboard" class="loginForm">
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary loginButton">Log in</button>
```

Then change your javascript to this:

```
    $('button.registerButton').click( function() {
        $('form.registerForm').submit();
    });
    $('button.loginButton').click( function() {
        $('form.loginForm').submit();
    });
```

Now you are able to submit two forms to two different **routes**.
One form would go to **samples** and the other to **dashboard**, so on your server (in Node) you can check which route it is.
I would suggest using one of the Node frameworks to work with your application.
You can try [Express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html). It will drastically simplify your work with routes.
It will allow you to write routes as easy as this:

```
app.post('/samples', function(req, res){
    // check register form
    // res.send('user' + req.body);
});
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){
    // check login form
    // res.send('user' + req.body);
});
```

You can read more on Express from a suggested list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8149496/2277855).

Answer (score 1):

You can add method="POST" and formaction="/samples" (and formaction="/dashboard" respectively) to the button tag, then the button is not confused to which endpoint it sends the form.

```
<button method="POST" formaction="/samples" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://shiya.io/parsing-forms-with-multiple-submit-buttons-in-node-js-with-express-4/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with nodejs handlebars and controller

1. My two form signature in a  html/handlebars file :

   ```
   <form action="/user/login/logData" method="POST">

   <form action="/user/login/regData" method="POST">
   ```
2. In my app.js/server.js file am added a controller like bellow

   ```
   const userAuthController=require("./controllers/loginregister.controller")
   app.use("/user",userAuthController)
   ```
3. My routes in controller file(./controllers/loginregister.controller.js)

   ```
   const express=require("express")
   const router=express.Router();
   router.get("/login",(req,res) => {
       console.log("page displayed")
       res.render("../views/users/registration");
   })

   router.post("/login/logData",(req,res) => {
       console.log("login")
       res.render("../views/users/registration");
   })

   router.post("/login/regData",(req,res) => {
       console.log("register")
       res.render("../views/users/registration");
   })

   module.exports = router;
   ```

Note: you can use code inside the specific post method to process the form data using mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input field for both the forn and than match the condition according to the form input, e.g.

```
app.post("/authentication", function (req, res) {
    if ("signIn" === req.body.formType) {
        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });

        //login() using passport "utility"
        req.login(newUser, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // this creates a cookie for the authentication
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        req.flash("message", "UserName or Password is Invalid");
                        res.redirect("/authentication");
                    } else {
                        res.redirect("/home");
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    } else if ("signUp" === req.body.formType) {
        User.register({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            username: req.body.email,
        }, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                const userFound = User.findOne({ username: req.body.email });
                if (userFound) {
                    req.flash("message", "User exists already maybe your evil twin! Try registering again");
                    res.redirect("/authentication");
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect("/authentication");
                }
            } else {
                res.redirect("/authentication");
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.send("Invalid input Form");
    }

});

    <form action="/authentication" method="post">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <p class="alert-danger" role="alert"><%= message %></p>
    <input type="email" class="form-control top mb-2" name="username placeholder="Email" required autofocus autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="password" class="form-control bottom mb-2" name="password" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Password" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="formType" value="signIn">
    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-2" type="submit">SignIn</button>

same for the other form......
this worked for me
```