# Two GET forms in one html page

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to do a pricing form, and each form has a hidden value, my goal is to send the value to the `'/billing'` route once the user click submit button, at first I thought it was a client-side problem, and I found this solution

[Processing multiple forms in one page using Mongodb and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960472/processing-multiple-forms-in-one-page-using-mongodb-and-node-js)

but it's not client-side problem.

For example

pricing-table.ejs

```
<form method="GET" action="/billing">
<input type="hidden" name="plan" value="monthly" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>

<form method="GET" action="/billing">
<input type="hidden" name="plan" value="yearly" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

app.js

```
app.get('/pricing', function(req, res) {
   var plan = req.body.plan;
   console.log(plan); // It will printout undefined, probably because It doesn't know which form belong to which one.

   res.render('pricing-table', { plan: plan });
});


app.get('/billing', function(req, res) {
   // Do some mongoose stuff 
});
```

Comment: Your second form is missing a quote after billing, is it a type here of the core itself?

Comment: Both of your forms are sending to your `/billing` route. Then in that `/billing` route you will have the value of `plan`. I don't see any problem here, other than the missing quote mentioned in previous comment. Also it doesn't seem very related to that other question, because they have two forms directed to two different routes and the purpose looks different.

Comment: I have corrected my missing quotes.

Comment: @Yura whenever I click submit, it will always get undefined.

Comment: So now the question is how do you look at those variables? You are posting forms to `/billing`, but you included code only from `/pricing`