# Check which form is used

Tags: php, html, forms

I created to do list, through a database,

But the sign in and sign up need to go through 1 manager... yet I dont know how to check which form is used. Hope someone can help me put the 2 pieces of PHP toghter in one manager! Thanks for all help in advance!

EDIT THIS IS HOW IT WORKS!

THE MANAGER FILE

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['action'] == 'login')  {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $wachtwoord = $_POST['pass'];
    $code       = sha1($wachtwoord);
    $pass       = crypt($code, 'ex');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE password = '$pass' AND email = '$email'";
    $result = $db_conn->query($sql)->rowCount();

    if ($result == 1)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
        header("Location: ../public/todo.php");
    }
    else{
        $ErrorMessage = "<strong>U heeft foutieve gegevens gebruikt, probeer het nog eens!</strong>";
        header("Location: ../public/index.php?message=$ErrorMessage");
    }
} else if($_GET['action'] == 'register')  {

    $ErrorMessage = "<strong>U moet een naam invullen!</strong>";
    if (empty($_POST['name'])){header("Location: ../public/signup.php?message=$ErrorMessage");die;}
    $ErrorMessage = "<strong>U moet een wachtwoord invullen!</strong>";
    if (empty($_POST['pass'])){header("Location: ../public/signup.php?message=$ErrorMessage");die;}
    $ErrorMessage = "<strong>U moet een geldige email invullen!</strong>";
    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){header("Location: ../public/signup.php?message=$ErrorMessage");die;}

    $email  = $_POST['email'];

    $qry="SELECT `email` FROM `tbl_users` ORDER BY `email`";
    $qryObj = $db_conn->prepare($qry);
    $qryObj->execute();

    $resultArr = $qryObj->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($resultArr as $row)
    {
        if ($email === $row['email']) {
            $ErrorMessage = "<strong>Deze mail bestaat al!</strong>";
            header("Location: ../public/signup.php?message=$ErrorMessage");die;
        }
    }


    $name   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $wachtwoord = $_POST['pass'];
    $code = sha1($wachtwoord);
    $pass = crypt($code,'ex');

    $verificatie='name='.$name.'&email='.$email.'&pass='.$pass;


    $subject = 'Verifeer uw email adres';
    $from = 'De TODO Servicedesk';
    $bericht = '/verificatie.php?'.$verificatie;

    ini_set('sendmail_from', $from);

    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers[] = "From: TODO Servicedesk <{$from}>";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: TODO Servicedesk <{$from}>";
    //$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";

    mail($email, $subject, $bericht, implode("\r\n", $headers) );
    $ErrorMessage = "<strong>Er is een activatiemail verstuurd!</strong>";
    header("Location: ../public/signup.php?message=$ErrorMessage");
}
```

?>

This are the FORMS

login form:

```
<section>
<form action="../app/account_manager.php?action=login" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Login!" class="btn btn-primary" name="login">
    </div>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['message'])!= null )
{
    echo $_GET['message'];
}
?>
```

Register Form:

```
<section>
<form action="../app/account_manager.php?action=register" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Registreer!" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
    </div>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['message'])!= null )
{
    echo $_GET['message'];
}
?>
```

Comment: why you need to put your both logic in one file ?

Comment: One manager needs to check registrations and logins, thats his task..

Comment: i know, i mean that it's always a good practice to break down your code, it will be easier to maintain , fix issues and track those issues .

Comment: you may use one page for two forms, but it will be good for you to use two separated files to handle each form

Comment: Yet I still want to learn how I can put it all in one manager... Can you maybe show in a awnser how to do it? Would be appriciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071250/how-to-place-two-forms-on-the-same-page , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459012/multiple-forms-and-one-processing-page

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Thanks zaph! This was just little test, im still a beginner ;) wont be posted online is just for self education! Ill go look in to that!

Thanks hassan im going to try it!

Comment: The fix is in my post! (not the updated protection yet..)

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden input in each forms. the first and second forms would have a unique name for examle: form_name="first" so

```
if ($_POST['form_name'] == 'first'){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you point your sign up form's action to the account manager script you could key off of the submit button "name" to do different action(s).

By the way, your sign in form's submit button doesn't currently carry a name attribute.

In  your manager script:

```
if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
    ... relevant registration code gets moved here ...
}else{
//or }elseif(isset($_POST['signin'])){  // if/when you give the button a name
    ...relevant sign in code goes here ...
}
```