# Submitting multiple forms to same action page using one button in php

Tags: php, html, css, forms

So I am trying to send data from multiple forms on the same page to the same action page using only one submit button.

So far I have tried using the form ID for all my forms and it is still unsuccessful. The first form is the only one that goes thru and I think that is because the action on its FORM tag, is executed before the rest of the forms can also be executed. Below I have put some sample code illustrating what I am try to do:

```html
<form method="post" action="example.php" id="formID">
//Some code here
</form>

<form method="post" action="example.php" id="formID">
//Some code here
</form>

<form method="post" action="example.php" id="formID">
//Some code here
</form>

<button type="submit" name="sub1" form="formID">Submit</button>
```

So how can I submit all three forms to the same page, using PHP?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: You mean you want to send all the controls on the page to the server, regardless of which form they're in? They why have more than one form in the fist place?

Comment: Any feedback on the previous question would be helpful. Why does this need to be three separate forms?

Comment: They are three separate forms because the way the page is currently designed, i cannot have one single form for all the controls. I tried making it one single form but the design of the page won't allow it, and unfortunately i did not design the page, i was asked to make the whole design of the web app work. So hence i need to know if there is a way to do something like this

Comment: Do you understand now Thabo? If so then please accept the answer so others know it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are submitting all the forms, but they all have the same action and ID. Check out this question: [multiple-forms-and-one-processing-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459012/multiple-forms-and-one-processing-page)

Firstly the HTML ID attribute must be unique. Once each form has it's own ID you can then properly parse the data in the $_GET variable from within your example.php file's action.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only using javascript and send the 3 request in the background.

For example. Mark your forms with specified class, for example `multiple_form`.

Then change your code to something like:

```html
<form method="post" class="multiple_form" action="example.php" id="formID">
//Some code here
</form>

<form method="post" class="multiple_form" action="example.php" id="formID">
//Some code here
</form>

<form method="post" class="multiple_form" action="example.php" id="formID">
//Some code here
</form>

<button class="multiple_form_sender" name="sub1">Submit</button>
```

Then add javascript to your code

```js
var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("multiple_form");

var sender = function(e) {
  const form = e.target;

  // Post data using Fetch
  fetch(form.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: new FormData(form)
  })

  // Prevent the default form submit
  e.preventDefault();
};

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', sender);
}

document.getElementById("multiple_form_sender").addEventListener('click', function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].submit();
    }
});
```

But if you don't want to send forms using javascript. You should consider one form with array parameters.

Comment: I didn't want to go the Javascript route. Can you elaborate more on the idea of using one form with an array parameters?